# Render template from Module in twig template

Tags: templating, modules

I have been searching around SE and the web in general for an answer to this. There seems to be plenty of solutions but none appear to be working for me.

I have a simple module that has a variable that gets called from a twig template in order to render a form.

The problem is no matter what I do I cannot get the module to render the HTML from within its own `/templates` directory.

The variable code is:

```
$oldMode = \Craft::$app->view->getTemplateMode();
\Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);
$html = \Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('../templates/_journey-planner.html');
\Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode($oldMode);
return $html;
```

This is taken from the Craft docs. I have also used:

```
Event::on(View::class,
          View::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_TEMPLATE_ROOTS,
          function (RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $e) {
                $e->roots['journeyplannermodule'] = 'journeyplannermodule/src/templates';
            }
        );
```

Within the module's `init()` function (not sure if this is actually required or not).

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to simply display this template within the twig template?

I am calling the variable method with:
`{{ craft.journeyPlannerModule.getJourneyPlanner }}`

Craft Version: 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now working. Turned out to be user error on my part. I had neglected the alias that I had created so the path to the template directory was incorrect.

Comment: Could you share example code that actually worked for you? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Gary, this is now a legacy project and the code has been archived. Unfortunately I do not have access too it any more, sorry,